# Sublime TFS auto checkout: Unable to save

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 with the Sublime TFS plugin. I can check out files without a problem. If I try to save a checked-in file, Sublime TFS will automatically check the file out. However, before the checkout is complete (slow servers), Sublime Text shows an unable to save dialog. I can dismiss the dialog and save the file (because checkout is complete), but it is an annoyance.

Does anyone know of a solution? Perhaps I can change the timeout on a save before the dialog shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I changed the argument in `thread.join()` from 5 to 10 seconds inside the `on_pre_save()` function, located in `sublime_tfs.py`. See code below.

```py
def on_pre_save(self, view):
    if not hasattr(self, 'manager'):
        self.manager = TfsManager()

    if self.manager.auto_checkout_enabled:
        path = view.file_name()
        if not (path is None):
            if is_readonly(path):
                thread = TfsRunnerThread(path, self.manager.auto_checkout)
                thread.start()
                ThreadProgress(view, thread, "Checkout...", "Checkout success: %s" % path)
                thread.join(10) # Changed from 5 to 10 seconds.
                if thread.isAlive():
                    sublime.set_timeout(lambda: "Checkout failed. Too long operation")
```